# Theming flutter apps

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, themes, darkmode

today I tried theming my app... I looked through a few packages and ended up using the stacked_themes package. Now I tried to implement the code as shown in the documentation but Im not sure how I have to implement the dialog

theme model file:

```
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:stacked_themes/stacked_themes.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MultiThemeModel {
  int index;
  String themeName;

  MultiThemeModel({required this.index, required this.themeName});
}

titlesForThemeModel(int index) {
  switch (index) {
    case 0:
      return 'Luxury Purple';
    case 1:
      return 'Red Fine Wine';
  }
  return 'No theme for index';
}

List<MultiThemeModel> get themes => List<MultiThemeModel>.generate(
    2,
    (index) =>
        MultiThemeModel(index: index, themeName: titlesForThemeModel(index)));

List<Widget> get widgets => themes
    .map((themeData) => MultipleThemeViewerWidget(themeData: themeData))
    .toList();

class MultipleThemeViewerWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  MultipleThemeViewerWidget({Key? key, required this.themeData})
      : super(key: key);
  final MultiThemeModel themeData;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
        right: 40,
      ),
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          getThemeManager(context).selectThemeAtIndex(themeData.index);
        },
        child: Container(
          height: 60,
          width: 105,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor.withOpacity(.3),
              border: Border.all(
                  color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor, width: 3)),
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              themeData.themeName,
              style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                textStyle: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 12,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

List of themes:

```
List<ThemeData> getThemes() {
  return [
    ThemeData(
      brightness: Brightness.light,
      primaryColor: purpleDesign[100],
      scaffoldBackgroundColor: purpleDesign[400],
      indicatorColor: purpleDesign[50],
      primaryColorLight: purpleDesign[300],
      hintColor: purpleDesign[400]),
    ThemeData(
      brightness: Brightness.light,
      primaryColor: redDesign[100],
      scaffoldBackgroundColor: redDesign[400],
      indicatorColor: redDesign[50],
      primaryColorLight: redDesign[300],
      hintColor: redDesign[400])
  ];
}
```

dialog:

```
showDialog(
                      context: context,
                      builder: (BuildContext context) {
                        return Dialog(
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                          ),
                          elevation: 1,
                          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).indicatorColor,
                          insetAnimationCurve: Curves.decelerate,
                          child: Container(
                            height: 170,
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                left: 33,
                                top: 85,
                              ),
                              child: Column(
                                children: [
                                  Row(children: [
                                    for(var theme in themes)
                                    MultipleThemeViewerWidget(themeData: ),],),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
```

my problem - I don't know what to pass to the themeData: in the forloop from the dialog... it would be really nice if somebody could help with this

thanks in advance:)

Comment: It looks like `themes` is already a `List<MultipleThemeViewerWidget>`- so you should be able to just have `Row(children: themes)`

Comment: Isn't it a list of type Them model? Because I have the list that's being generated but without any ui... That's why I made the list of widgets as I did... Maybe I understood you wrong?

Comment: Ah, my mistake, I did misread your code. But actually the variable `widgets` does contain the `List<MultipleThemeViewerWidget>` - That's the list that you can pass to the `Row` widget

Comment: omg this is such an obvious mistake by me.... i tried putting widgets inside the squared brackets.... but I got teh error that i cant provide type list<widget> to type widget but thats obviously not an error if I write it without the brackets... thank you a lot